# How to query with Criteria API a base class?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

The entities look like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@Inheritance(
        strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED
)
public class User {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "username", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password", unique = false, nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "role", nullable = false)
    private UserRole userRole;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public UserRole getUserRole() {
        return userRole;
    }

    public void setUserRole(UserRole userRole) {
        this.userRole = userRole;
    }

}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer extends User {

    @Column(name = "address", unique = false, nullable = false)
    private String address;

    @Column(name = "consent_given", unique = false, nullable = false)
    private boolean consentGiven;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "customer",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Cart cart;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "customer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Favorites favorites;

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public boolean isConsentGiven() {
        return consentGiven;
    }

    public void setConsentGiven(boolean consentGiven) {
        this.consentGiven = consentGiven;
    }

    public void setCart(Cart cart) { this.cart = cart; }

    public Cart getCart() { return cart; }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Customer{" +
                "address='" + address + '\'' +
                ", consentGiven=" + consentGiven +
                ", cart=" + cart +
                ", orders=" + orders +
                ", favorites=" + favorites +
                '}';
    }

}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cart")
public class Cart {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "cart_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "cart_id")
    private List<CartItem> listOfCartItems = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
    private Customer customer;

    @Column(name = "cart_total_price", unique = false)
    private double price;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<CartItem> getListOfCartItems() {
        return listOfCartItems;
    }

    public void setListOfCartItems(List<CartItem> listOfCartItems) {
        this.listOfCartItems = listOfCartItems;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double totalPrice) {
        this.price = totalPrice;
    }

}
```

I need to use Criteria API to get a cart by customer's id.
The things is, as I have seen, the primary key from the base class will be inherited by Customer's class in MySQL even if it is not written in Customer's class.
My question is, how do I query over the 3 tables to get the cart of a specific customer by his id, if the customer inherits the primary key from the base class?
I did a query (even if it is not useful), if a primary key is in the Customer's class:

```
Cart resultedCart;

CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Cart> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Cart.class);
Root<Cart> cart = query.from(Cart.class);
Join<Cart, Customer> customer = cart.join("customer");
ParameterExpression<Long> idParameter = criteriaBuilder.parameter(Long.class);
       
query.select(cart).where(criteriaBuilder.equal(customer.get("id"), idParameter));
TypedQuery<Cart> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(query);

try {
     resultedCart = typedQuery.setParameter(idParameter, id).getSingleResult();
} catch (NoResultException noResultException) {
     throw new NoCartFoundException("The searched cart does not exist!", noResultException);
} finally {
     entityManager.close();
}

return resultedCart;
```

and I tried based on this code to make what I need, but unfortunately, without success.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```java
Cart resultedCart;

CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Cart> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Cart.class);
Root<Cart> cart = query.from(Cart.class);

query.select(cart).where(criteriaBuilder.equal(cart.get("customer").get("id"), idParameter));

TypedQuery<Cart> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(query);

try {
     resultedCart = typedQuery.getSingleResult();
} catch (NoResultException noResultException) {
     throw new NoCartFoundException("The searched cart does not exist!", noResultException);
} finally {
     entityManager.close();
}

return resultedCart;
```